# Use of deprecated `page`/`offset` parameter in browse error from ALGOLIA

Tags: java, spring-boot, search, algolia

I was trying to fetch all data from Algolia using browseFrom() API with pagination as below.

```
 BrowseIndexResponse<Test> items = index
                .browseFrom(new BrowseIndexQuery().setPage(pageNumber).setHitsPerPage(pageSize));
```

But after a particular page i got an error as shown below

```
    {"message":"Use of deprecated `page`/`offset` parameter in browse:
     you should pass the `cursor` parameter to fetch next page.
     Please upgrade your api client if necessary","status":400}
```

Note:
algolia shows nbPages: 82, nbHits: 16341

I have tried changing Algolia version and al, but it is not working. any help is appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally found the solution,

```
public TestResponse getAllTestDate(String cursor, int pageSize) {
    final SearchIndex<Test> index = client.initIndex(indexName, Test.class);
    TestResponseDate testResponseData = new ProductListResponse();
    BrowseIndexResponse<Test> items = null;
    if (cursor != null) {
        items = index.browseFrom(new BrowseIndexQuery().setHitsPerPage(pageSize).setCursor(cursor));
    } else {
        items = index.browseFrom(new BrowseIndexQuery().setHitsPerPage(pageSize));
    }
    testResponseData .setCursor(items.getCursor());
    testResponseData .setTest(items.getHits());
    return testResponseData ;
}
```

First time we are not passing 'cursor' value, After first hit we will get a 'cursor' value from algolia, use that for next algolia hit. repeat this until we are getting 'cursor' value as null (that means, for last page algolia returns 'cursor' value as null).